# Mainly, First, second, third

Tags: grammaticality

It is correct?

> Reduction first in starch, second in glucose and fructose concentrations.

from "first", I mean "mainly". May I use "mainly" and "second"?

Comment: This sentence also no verb.

Comment: It's just a title

Comment: It does not work as a title. At all. A title would simply say "Reduction in starch, glucose, and fructose concentrations". It would also have no period.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it was correct but bad.

*First* is sometimes used to mean "mainly", but not very often.

As such it stands as a case where you could defend it by going of and finding it attested in this use, but it would remain that people are likely to interpret the title as relating to temporal order; that the starch is reduced before the sugars. We don't write correctly so that we can argue we've written correctly; we write correctly to aid our writing effectively.

*Primarily* while originating as a near-synonym of *firstly* is now more likely to be interpreted in the "mainly" sense:

> Reduction primarily in starch, secondarily in glucose and fructose, concentrations.

You also need that comma after fructose to make the "secondarily in glucose and fructose" clause parenthetical if you want "concentrations" to be linked to "starch" which I'm guessing you do.